# Spring custom error response: timeStamp vs timestamp

Tags: spring, http, timestamp, response

I made a custom error message

```
private final ??? timestamp;
private final HttpStatus status;
private final String message;
private List<ValidationError> errors;
```

The thing is that no matter the timestamp field type it seems like somewhere this field gets overwritten.

For example, say that timestamp field is a String. By posting a http request i get an error in this format

```
 "status": "CONFLICT",
 "message": "UserNameTakenException",
 "errors": null,
 "timeStamp": "this is a date"
```

Why timestamp becomes timeStamp? Not only that, but having

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
private final LocalDateTime timestamp;
```

produces errors with 2 timestamps!

```
 "timestamp": "26-06-2021 10:22:36",
 "status": "CONFLICT",
 "message": "UserNameTakenException",
 "errors": null,
 "timeStamp": "2021-06-26T22:22:36.283862"
```

What the heck is happening here? Im using an ControllerAdvice to catch the exception and then produce the response

```
  @ExceptionHandler(UserNameTakenException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT)
  public ResponseEntity<Object> handleUserNameTakenException(UserNameTakenException ex, WebRequest request) {
    ErrorResponse errorResponse = new ErrorResponse(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, ex.getMessage());  
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body(errorResponse);
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Ok, so i tried to change the custom error's getter for timestamp

```
public LocalDateTime getTimeStamp() {
    return this.timestamp;
}
```

The getter is being used not only to retrieve the value (which is private) but also to name the json response field.

So, having the getter's name "getTimestamp" OR having no getter at all solves the problem (i get only one timestamp).
Having the getter's name "getFoo" creates my custom "timestamp" and also a "foo" named field in json with the form

````
"foo": "2021-06-26T23:28:54.664794"```
````